# Unknown anime with a little white hair(?) boy who can communicate with spirits such as from nature

Tags: story-identification, anime

The only thing I can remember of the show is the boy has some sort of power to communicate with spirits of all kinds. He travels around the world on a giant flying turtle and also lives on it along with other spirits. There might have been a forest on the turtle as well.

He goes around and tries to calm down any spirits who went berserk (and also collects/befriends them?), such as elemental spirits like the wind as I remember him engaging with one who created a giant twister, the boy can also use the powers of other spirits who he befriended to aid him in on his adventure.

The boy is also accompanied by a normal girl (might have been rescued by the boy on the first ep. can't remember) who helps him.

Goal was unknown/forgotten.

Comment: And i think the girl also rides like those two-seater mini airplane!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be [**Michel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_(TV_series)):

[image: pic]

> The series begins with an artifact being stolen from a museum by a group of thieves called the Black Hammer Gang. Following their escape, they are pursued by a young girl named Kim who wants to take her father's inventions (which the Black Hammer Gang had stolen) back from them. Kim chases the thieves until both the Black Hammer Gang and Kim fall on a strange island inhabited by fairies and its guardian Michel. The Black Hammer Gang tries to steal the life source of the island (and in essence the universe since the fairies represent nature) called the tree of life. Causing damage to the land and kidnapping the fairies, Michel and Kim have to combat the Black Hammer gang and take back the fairies in order to restore balance to nature.

The two main character are:

> **Michel**: Michel is the title character and male protagonist. The Guardian of the Tree of life and protector of the fairies, of nature, Michel is very kind hearted and has a great love for and respect for nature and also appears to possess some telepathic powers, being able to sense another person's thoughts and feelings just by touching another person's hand.
>
> **Kim**: The series' main female protagonist. Kim first meets Michel after her plane crashes on the island, it is here where she meets the other fairies and sees the Tree of Life. Following the Black Hammer Gang's attack and the Tree of Life dying she and Michel set off to rescue the other fairies and save the Tree of Life. Following an attack on her father's lab by the Black Hammer Gang Salame stole one of her father's inventions, a space ship, which would later become their main base. As she escaped the laboratory was destroyed and Kim's father was presumably killed. As a result, she harbors a strong dislike for the black Hummer Gang and is determined to stop them no matter the cost. Kim is also the pilot of a small multipurpose aircraft which she calls Honeybee.

Comment: This is definitely it! Thank you so much!